# What is the best way to make glass in blender 2.92?

Tags: transparency, glass

I know this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33134/how-to-make-an-object-transparent) has been asked before, but it's for different versions. This material setting does not seem to exist anywhere I look.

For a project of mine I need a glass that is transparent but also reflects some light. The results in the answer linked above seems to look really nice but as mentioned, the setting does not seem to exist anymore.

I've tried using a Glass BSDF, but the settings aren't nearly as deep and I can't seem to get it to reflect anything.

Comment: Although questions with "best" in them tend to call for opinions, there is an exhaustive factual answer to this question.  Unfortunately the TL;DNR is "there isn't one because what's best depends on what purpose the glass serves in the scene." And, these days, it also depends very much on what render engine you are using.

Comment: @MartyFouts Any render engine works for me. The glass should reflect something quite clearly but let some light through.

Comment: For Eevee you could try Ryan King's recent tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYyUMMboZFk).

Comment: Try the principled shader with transmission set to 1 and roughness set low.  You can experiment with the IOR value. In EEVEE be sure to set the material's Blend mode to one of the Alpha modes.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: Hi :). Keep in mind reflections/refractions will depend mostly on your scene lighting. Glass BSDF shader is physically accurate for most uses.